# Conditional probability with sympy

Tags: probability

I've also asked it on SO because it is more about a library than actual math, but I took a chance by asking it here as well.

I want to use Sympy to calculate the following

Posterior

$$P(\Theta=1| y) = \frac{P(\Theta=1)P(y|\Theta=1)}{P(\Theta=1)P(y|\Theta=1) + P(\Theta=2)P(y|\Theta=2) }
= \frac{1/2*N(1, \sigma)}{1/2*N(1, \sigma) + 1/2*N(2, \sigma) }$$

Where $\Theta$ can be either 1 or 2 with prob 0.5 and $y\sim N(\Theta, \sigma)$

This is the code I'm using in Sympy

```
from sympy.stats import Normal, density, DiscreteUniform, P, given
from sympy import Symbol, pprint, symbols, Symbol, Eq
sigma = Symbol("sigma", positive=True)
mu = DiscreteUniform('mu', [1,2])
N = Normal('normal', mu, sigma)

sampling_dist = given(N, Eq(mu, 1))
prior = P(Eq(mu, 1))
marginal = P(Eq(mu, 1))*given(N, Eq(mu, 1))+P(Eq(mu, 2))*given(N, Eq(mu,2))
post = prior * sampling_dist / marginal
```

Now I want to

1. be able to print the equation for the posterior distribution (I expect sigma and x to be the only unknown)
2. Plot the posterior by fixing sigma with a known value

I tried to print the equation by asking the density with

```
density(post)(Symbol('x'))
```

And I get the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-9b0e1c9ada72> in <module>()
----> 1 density(post)(Symbol('x'))

/Users/alexis/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sympy/stats/rv.py in density(expr, condition, evaluate, numsamples, **kwargs)
    692                 **kwargs)
    693 
--> 694     return Density(expr, condition).doit(evaluate=evaluate, **kwargs)
    695 
    696 

/Users/alexis/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sympy/stats/rv.py in doit(self, evaluate, **kwargs)
    643             isinstance(pspace(expr), SinglePSpace)):
    644             return expr.pspace.distribution
--> 645         result = pspace(expr).compute_density(expr, **kwargs)
    646 
    647         if evaluate and hasattr(result, 'doit'):

/Users/alexis/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sympy/stats/rv.py in pspace(expr)
    430         return rvs[0].pspace
    431     # Otherwise make a product space
--> 432     return ProductPSpace(*[rv.pspace for rv in rvs])
    433 
    434 

/Users/alexis/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sympy/stats/rv.py in __new__(cls, *spaces)
    278         # Overlapping symbols
    279         if len(symbols) < sum(len(space.symbols) for space in spaces):
--> 280             raise ValueError("Overlapping Random Variables")
    281 
    282         if all(space.is_Finite for space in spaces):

ValueError: Overlapping Random Variables
```

Even if I subs sigma with a constant I get the same error. I (obviously) don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you for your time

Comment: may be suitable for [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Can you link to the SO question?

Comment: It's the exact same question, copy pasted. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32443970/conditional-probability-with-sympy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`N`, `sampling_dist` and the `given()` constructs are *random variables*. To compute the conditional distribution function you should use their *probability distribution functions*, not the variables themselves.

```
>>> sampling_dist
normal    # name of the variable
>>> sampling_dist.pspace
SingleContinuousPSpace(normal, NormalDistribution(1, sigma))
>>> sampling_dist.pspace.pdf
sqrt(2)*exp(-(normal - 1)**2/(2*sigma**2))/(2*sqrt(pi)*sigma)
```

Comment: Yes thank you very much. I made a conceptual mistake. I though I was getting a distribution and not a random variable that follows that distribution.